# Jquery horizontal accordion click to contract

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have this script I am using for a horizontal accordion. You can see the functionality here:
http://jsfiddle.net/vXpPg/

I am looking to have the open slide close on click as well.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please include your problem code as well as the jsfiddle link in your posts. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle

Comment: I haven't noticed any problem, it works, just expand the result area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/vXpPg/1/

I modified your `click` function to check the width of the section you are clicking on first.  If this width is equal to what you wrote as `maxWidth` then we know that we just want to collapse it (change its width to the `minWidth` setting).  If it is not, then we know it must be a small section, and need to expand like normal (the code you already had).

```
$("ul li").click(

function() {
    /*
     * I added this
     */
    if ($(this).width() == maxWidth) {
        $(this).animate({
            width: minWidth + "px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 400
        });
    } else {
        /*
         * You had this
         */
        $(lastBlock).animate({
            width: minWidth + "px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 400
        });
        $(this).animate({
            width: maxWidth + "px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 400
        });
    }
    lastBlock = this;
});​
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259 to include the essential parts of 
the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should fix it :

```
lastBlock = $("#a1");
maxWidth = 450;
minWidth = 50;

$("ul li").click(

function() {
    if (lastBlock != this) {
        $(lastBlock).animate({
            width: minWidth + "px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 400
        });
        $(this).animate({
            width: maxWidth + "px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 400
        });
        lastBlock = this;
    } else {
        $(this).animate({
            width: minWidth + "px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 400
        });
    }
});​
```